# Cloning an encrypted hard disk to a different computer

Tags: 12.10, kernel, encryption, clone

I'm using 12.10 with full-disk encryption. Can I clone my full-encrypted hard disk from an old laptop and write it, as-is, to a new laptop and expect everything to work correctly right away?

If there is no problem from encryption point-of-view, is there something else to consider, like wrong drivers getting loaded etc, X.org being totally off etc? What should I look into beforehand to make it less painful?

Answer (score 0):

It is just to clone and use the same method used to decrypt.

One possible problem in a newer system is with library versions and package names that might have been changed.